# Trying to add text to a SharePoint Display Form. Currently only able to add to Edit and New Form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am adding some JS libraries to allow owners of SharePoint sites to add some functionality to their forms and pages by referencing various scripts in the Asset Libraries.  I have this one script that allows the user to insert Section headings above any field in the EditForm and NewForm.

However, this does not work on the DispForm.  The user places the reference to the script in a Script Editor and pass parameters (Section Heading and Field (to insert the heading before).  My reference looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-color="" data-sections="Add New UID Anomally-UID" src="../../SiteAssets/js-enterprise/AddSections.js"></script>
```

My actual script in SiteAssets is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  // Get a list of views to turn off the headers
  var this_js_script = $('script[src*=AddSections]');
  var lists = this_js_script.attr('data-sections'); 
  var str_array = lists.split(',');

  var color = this_js_script.attr('data-color'); 
  // over-ride color if there is no value #96c03d
  if (typeof color == 'undefined' || color == null || color == ''){
    color = "#000000";
  }

  for(var n = 0; n < str_array.length; n++) {
    // Trim the excess whitespace.
    str_array[n] = str_array[n].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
    // Add additional code here, such as:
    var str2_array = str_array[n].split('-');
    AddSectionBeforeField(str2_array[0],str2_array[1],color);
  }
});

function AddSectionBeforeField(sectionText,fieldName,colorcode){
  var $fieldTR=$(".ms-standardheader nobr:contains('"+fieldName+"')").closest("tr");
  $fieldTR.before("<tr style='background-color:white'><td colspan='2' class='ms-formbody' style='padding:0; color: "+colorcode+";'><div style='font-size:22px;margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;font-family: Oswald';'>"+sectionText+"</div></td></tr>");
}
```

How can I either make this work for both or change this to work for a DispForm?

Answer (score 1):

The Edit Form and Display Form are different.

[image]

[image]

So you need use different selector for different forms.

Below jQuery selector for display form.

```
 $("h3.ms-standardheader:contains('Current Route Date')");
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the forms are different (I should have provided that I knew that, sorry), but how would the function, AddSectionBeforeField to support the DispForm?  This area is not my expertise.  Thank you